# All footnote numbers should begin on the same horizontal position

Tags: footnotes, alignment

I’m trying to have all footnote numbers begin on the same horizontal position.
The definition that is commented out in the mwe will be in the final document, it creates a space between the footnote number and the footnote.
The result should be the footnote number starting on the left, in line with the text of the main body.
There should then be a rather wide space followed by the footnote text.
In my mwe, it works well until I get to footnote number 10.

As such, the example in the image doesn’t look bad, but once the footnote numbers are not superscript (as they will be in the final document) and on the left, them not being aligned looks weird.
I have commented it out in the mwe because the problem occurs whether the definition is active or not.
How can I let the footnote numbers start at the same horizontal space while the footnote text also starts at another fixed horizontal space (as if they were left aligned in a two column table)?In my mwe, it works well until I get to footnote number 10.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\deffootnote{2em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\hskip 1.5em}

\begin{document}
This%
\footnote{Footnote.}
is%
\footnote{Footnote.}
some%
\footnote{Footnote.}
text%
\footnote{Footnote.}
and%
\footnote{Footnote.}
here%
\footnote{Footnote.}
follows%
\footnote{Footnote.}
some%
\footnote{Footnote.}
more%
\footnote{Footnote.}
text.%
\footnote{Footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KomaScript documentation has an example for achieving left-aligned footnote marks (part of chapter 3.14. in my documentation). It involves creating a box for the footnote mark and left-aligning the box content. In your example that would be: `\deffootnote{2em}{1em}{\makebox[1em][l]{\thefootnotemark}\hskip 1.5em}`. Adjust the lengths to your liking.

Comment: Somehow I didn’t see that in the documentation (of which I own an older print and mostly use the latest version as pdf).